# Change selected text in jHtmlArea

Tags: jquery, jhtmlarea

I'm using jHtmlArea and i need to create a custom button to wrap text inside a `span` tag.
I managed to understand how to put the button in the toolbar but i cannot understand what i have to do to get the selected text, change it and put it back in that jHtmlArea iframe.

If someone can help, i'll appreciate.

Thank u all

Answer (score 0):

I used this for example:

```
            {
                css: "float-left",
                text: "Pull left",
                action: function(btn) {
                    var s = this.getSelectedHTML();
                       s = "<span style='/*some css rules*/'>" + s + "</span>";
                    this.pasteHTML(s);
                }
            }
```